# Trying to add banner ad ,but an error is caused telling error inflating

Tags: android, development-environment

I have created an book app in which I have to implement banner ad,so when I was putting    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1',then an error telling Attribute merger failed came,so I added     android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true ,and problem was solved,but all the previous activity file had problem ,so I migrated to android and everything is fine,but when I am testing it on USB Debug phone ,then Activity 1 is opening (total activity:3,1 for icon  launcher,2 content list and 3 of content)

Logcat is like this;

```
     08/20 20:55:42:     Launching app
        $ adb install-multiple -r -t       C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk
       C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk 
   C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk   
  C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk     
  C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk 
  C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk 
  C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk 
  C

    :\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk
      C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk
      C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk   
      C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk 
      C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk
     C:\Users\DELL\AndroidStudioProjects\Stories\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
     Split APKs installed in 21 s 798 ms
     $ adb shell am start  
    -n "com.example.stories/com.example.stories.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
     Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
     Connected to process 14000 on device samsung-sm_j600g-5200701fbc2465f9
     Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
     W/example.storie: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
     I/chatty: uid=10559(com.example.stories) identical 10 lines
     W/example.storie: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
     I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
     I/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null.
     I/DecorView: createDecorCaptionView >> DecorView@15ef02c[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
     W/example.storie: Unsupported class loader
     W/example.storie: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
     I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module   
     com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module  
     com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:20300
        Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 20300
     V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version 

    >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
     I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:7 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:9
        Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite, version >= 9
    V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
    W/example.storie: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    W/example.storie: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
    W/example.storie: Unsupported class loader
    W/example.storie: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
    W/example.storie: Unsupported class loader
    W/example.storie: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
    D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
    D/EmergencyMode: [EmergencyManager] android createPackageContext successful
    D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=79
    D/ViewRootImpl@15d9606[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@15ef02c[MainActivity] TM=true MM=false
    D/ViewRootImpl@15d9606[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
    W/Activity: AppLock checkAppLockState locked:false verifying:false pkgName = com.example.stories isInMultiWindowMode:false showWhenLocked:false
    D/ViewRootImpl@15d9606[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][720,1480] new=[0,0][720,1480] result=0x1 surface={false 0} changed=false
    I/FA-Ads: App measurement is starting up, version: 16251
        To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    I/DecorView: mWindow.mActivityCurrentConfig is null.
    I/DecorView: createDecorCaptionView >> DecorView@8c1a5bf[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.stories, PID: 14000
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stories/com.example.stories.Main2Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            at android.app.ActivityThread

.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960)
            at 

        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                at android

.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:902)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
            at com.example.stories.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:38)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7340)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7331)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
            Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm) /

data/app/com.example.stories-GInON3zF9elFx71lxmHm1Q==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
            at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
            at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
            at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
            at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
            at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:766)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:849)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1090)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2563)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6131)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
                    ... 6 more
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14000 SIG: 9
    Application terminated.
```

---

```
MY Second Activity(Main Activity 2 in which hopefully error is coming ,as its not opening)

    package com.example.stories;

    import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main2Activity<mRecyclerView> extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Main2Activity" ;

private AdView mAdView;


private Context mContext;
ArrayList<String> titleArrayList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    mContext = Main2Activity.this;

    titleArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.ANDROCLES);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.ANT_AND_GRASSHOPPER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.AVARACIOUS_AND_ENVIOUS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.BELLING_THE_CAT);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.FOUR_OXEN_AND_LION);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.FOX_AND_CAT);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.FOX_AND_LION);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.FOX_COCK_AND_DOG);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.HARE_WITH_MANY_FRIENDS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.HERCULES_AND_THE_WAGGONER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.LION_AND_STATUE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.LION_FOX_AND_BEAST);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.MAN_BOY_AND_DONKEY);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.MEMOIRS_OF_A_YELLOW_DOG);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_ASS_AND_THE_THE_LAPDOG);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_ASS_BRAIN);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_ASS_IN_THE_LION_SKIN);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_BALDMAN_AND_THE_FLY);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_BELLY_AND_THE_MEMBERS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_BOASTING_TRAVELLER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_BOY_WHO_CRIED_WOLF);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_BUNDLE_OF_STICKS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_CAMEL_AND_THE_BABY);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_CAT_MAIDEN);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_COCK_AND_THE_PEARL);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_COWS_AND_TIGER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_CROW_AND_PITCHER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_DOG_AND_THE_SHADOW);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_DOG_AND_THE_WOLF);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_DOG_IN_THE_MANGER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_EAGLE_AND_THE_ARROW);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FARMER_AND_THE_WELL);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FISHER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FISHER_AND_LITTLE_FISH);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FOUR_STUDENTS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FOX_AND_GOAT);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FOX_THE_CROW);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FOX_AND_THE_MOSQUITOES);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FOX_AND_THE_STORK);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FROG_AND_THE_MASK);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FOX_WITHOUT_A_TAIL);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FROG_AND_THE_OX);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_LION_AND_THE_MOUSE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_LABOURER_AND_NIGHTINGALE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_JAY_AND_THE_PEACOCK);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_HORSE_HUNTER_AND_THE_STAG);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_HART_IN_THE_OX_STALL);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_HART_AND_THE_HUNTER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_HARES_AND_THE_FROG);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_GOLDEN_EGG);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_FROG_DESIRING_KING);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_LION_IN_LOVE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_LION_SHARE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MAN_AND_HIS_TWO_WIVES);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MAN_AND_SATYR);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MAN_AND_THE_CAT);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MAN_AND_THE_SERPENT);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MAN_AND_THE_WOOD);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MAN_AND_THE_WOODGOD);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MIDAS_TOUCH);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MISER_AND_HIS_GOLD);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MILKMAID_AND_HER_PAIL);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_MOUNTAINS_IN_LABOUR);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_NURSE_AND_THE_WOLF);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_OLDMAN_AND_DEATH);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_ONE_EYED_DOE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_PEACOCK_AND_JUNO);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_SERPENT_AND_THE_FILE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_SICK_LION);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_SKYLIGHT_ROOM);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_SWALLOWS_AND_THE_BIRDS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_TORTOISE_AND_THE_BIRD);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_TRUMPSTER_TAKE_PRISONER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_TWO_CRABS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_TWO_FELLOWS_AND_THE_BEAR);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_TWO_POTS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_WIND_AND_THE_SUN);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_WOLF_AND_THE_CRANE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_WOLF_AND_THE_KID);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_WOLF_AND_THE_LAMB);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_WOODMAN_AND_SERPENT);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_YOUNG_THIEF_AND_HIS_MOTHER);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.TOWN_MOUSE_AND_COUNTRY_MOUSE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.TREE_AND_REED);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.WOLF_IN_SHEEP_CLOTHING);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.A_COSMPOLITE_IN_A_CAFE);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.BREMEN_TOWN_MUSICIANS);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.LITTLE_RED_RIDING_HOOD);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_STORY_OF_AN_HOUR);
    titleArrayList.add(com.example.stories.Constants.THE_GIFT_OF_MAGI);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

        }
    });

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest =new  AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);



    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.title_layout_recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

    com.example.stories.TitleAdapter adapter = new com.example.stories.TitleAdapter(mContext, titleArrayList, new CustomItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int Position) {

            Intent desIntent = new Intent(mContext,DescriptionActivity.class);
            desIntent.putExtra("titles",titleArrayList.get(Position));
            startActivity(desIntent);
            desIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            Toast.makeText(mContext,"clicked"+titleArrayList.get(Position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.share_button:
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody ="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.stories";
            String shareSubject = "Your Subject Here";

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareBody);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareSubject);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share Using"));

            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MY MANIFEST FILE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.stories">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DescriptionActivity"
              android:parentActivityName=".Main2Activity"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

BUILD GRADLE

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.stories"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}




    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'


}
```

Comment: Pls if required anything else ask

Comment: Could you share your gradle file.

Comment: I did ,sir pls hlp me now

Comment: Try removing the following line and let me know if it worked.
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview'

Comment: No,it didn't  ,same thing happened.

Comment: Also, why is Main2Activity<mRecyclerView> there? I believe it should just be Main2Activity?

Comment: I removed it,but still app is crashing.